# Trying to see how many Edit Texts are filled in by the user by using an array list

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-edittext

The edit texts are all automatically filled with zero. So I am trying to count how many are not and that should be the number this method returns.

```
 private double numOfClasses(ArrayList<EditText> x){
    double r=0;
    for(int i=0; i<x.size(); i++){
        String y;
        y=x.get(i).toString();
        if(y=="0"==false){
            r++;


        }





    }



    return r;
}
```

Comment: The method is supposed to take an array list of EditTexts as the argument. That has already been created.

Comment: y=="0"==false => !y.equals("0")  . Also maybe y=x.get(i).getText();

Comment: !y.equals("0"), this worked thank you so much!